# Check if READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is needed to to read from specific Uri

Tags: android

I would like to check if I need Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to read from given Uri.

This is needed to properly handle incoming Intents to my app. For example, if I share image to my app from WhatsApp and my app doesn't have read permission that's OK. I still can read from this Uri since WhatsApp granted me permission to read this Uri. Google Photos, however, share Uris as an external storage Uri and to read from it I need to prompt user to give my app permission to read from external storage.

I know I could always ask user to provid my app read permission but I would like to avoid this whenever possible.

Comment: you can check if the URI contains the `Environment.getExternalStorage<blah-blah, don't remember what>()`, and request permissions based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle it but you can catch the `SecurityException` and then request requisite permissions:

```
try {
    getContentResolver().query(uri, ...);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // Request storage perms here
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    }, REQ_READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
}
```

Comment: That's the problem, I don't read this image myself but I am using image processing library to handle incoming photo. So I don't need to read it, just to check if permission is needed

Comment: So how does the lib handle not having the permission? Does it propagate the exception upwards?

Comment: It propagates the error to onActivityResult, so you are right, I could handle error there and just repeat whole operation

Answer (score 0):

```
    if( PERMISSION_GRANTED != checkUriPermission( uri, android.os.Process.myPid(), android.os.Process.myUid(),
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)) {
        // request permission here
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to handle an important edge case. I just tried it on a URI, that points to external storage but [doesn't need the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) since it points to a file under a directory returned by `getExternalFilesDir(String)`.

Perhaps this caveat in the documentation explains why:
`This only checks for permissions that have been explicitly granted -- if the given process/uid has more general access to the URI's content provider then this check will always fail.`

Comment: @Benjamin I think in case of accessing URI returned by ANOTHER app's getExternalFilesDir() you still need the permission. In case you are accessing your own URI you can handle this case in your code because you know about it.